# Exception while saving android application data in google app engine datastore

Tags: android, google-app-engine, jdo

Below mentioned method is a method from my entityendpoint class :-

```
@ApiMethod(name = "insertEventEntity")
public EventEntity insertEventEntity(EventEntity eventEntity) {

    PersistenceManagerFactory pmfInstance =
            JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

    PersistenceManager pm = pmfInstance.getPersistenceManager();


    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(EventEntityEndpoint.class.getName());

    log.info("pm="+pm);

    EventEntity event = new EventEntity("First", "First", "18/7/2015", "6:00", "18/7/2015", "7:00");

    try
    {
        pm.makePersistent(event);

        log.info("event="+event);
    }
    finally
    {
        pm.close();
    }

    return event
}
```

Below mentioned code is the code from where the above method is getting called:-

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
{

    EventEntityApi.Builder builder = new EventEntityApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory(), null).setRootUrl("https://minote-997.appspot.com/_ah/api/");
                // end of optional local run code

    EventEntity eventEntity = new EventEntity();

    EventEntityApi eventApi = builder.build();

    try
    {
        System.out.println("inserting events");

        EventEntityApi.InsertEventEntity insertEventEntity = eventApi.insertEventEntity(eventEntity);

        insertEventEntity.execute();

        System.out.println("inserting events1");
    }
    catch(IOException exception)
    {
        System.out.println("IoException ="+exception.getStackTrace());
    }
    return "Success";
}
```

The method insertEventEntity() metioned above gets called but i am getting some error log in google developer console -> Monitoring -> Logs. Complete exception stacktrace is as follows :-

```
I 13:22:12.038 org.datanucleus.PersistenceConfiguration setProperty: Property datanucleus.appengine.singletonPMFForName unknown - will be ignored
I 13:22:12.039 org.datanucleus.PersistenceConfiguration setProperty: Property datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns unknown - will be ignored
I 13:22:12.040 org.datanucleus.PersistenceConfiguration setProperty: Property datanucleus.appengine.datastoreReadConsistency unknown - will be ignored
I 13:22:13.337 org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper getJDOExceptionForNucleusException: Exception thrown
  There is no available StoreManager of type "appengine". Make sure that you have put the relevant DataNucleus store plugin in your CLASSPATH and if defining a connection via JNDI or DataSource you also need to provide persistence property "datanucleus.storeManagerType"
  org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: There is no available StoreManager of type "appengine". Make sure that you have put the relevant DataNucleus store plugin in your CLASSPATH and if defining a connection via JNDI or DataSource you also need to provide persistence property "datanucleus.storeManagerType"
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContext.java:506)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.initialise(NucleusContext.java:288)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:660)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:326)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_$1.run(Method_.java:167)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.privilegedInvoke(Method_.java:164)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.invoke_(Method_.java:125)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.invoke(Method_.java:45)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.security.AccessController_.doPrivileged(AccessController_.java:63)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:1093)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:919)
    at com.gp.app.minote.backend.entities.EventEntityEndpoint.insertEventEntity(EventEntityEndpoint.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_$1.run(Method_.java:167)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.privilegedInvoke(Method_.java:164)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.invoke_(Method_.java:125)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.invoke(Method_.java:45)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:160)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:118)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter.doFilter(AsyncCacheFilter.java:59)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:257)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:482)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:230)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:234)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am also attaching the image of my external libraries in android studio :-

[image: External libraries required for google app engine data store and jdo]

Please also find the attached jdoconfig.xml file placed in /webapp/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF folder:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig">

    <persistence-manager-factory name="transactions-optional">
        <property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass"
            value="org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.RetainValues" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.appengine.singletonPMFForName" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreReadConsistency" value="EVENTUAL" />
    </persistence-manager-factory>
</jdoconfig>
```

I am using android studio as IDE for development. The pieces of code attached above are from my android app. I am using google app engine datastore as backend for my application and for entity persistence i am using JDO framework.

Please suggest what could be the reason for the above mentioned exception(stacktrace).

Comment: The message *There is no available StoreManager of type "appengine". Make sure that you have put the relevant DataNucleus store plugin in your CLASSPATH* is clear enough. You don't have "datanucleus-appengine" jar in your CLASSPATH

Comment: Sandeep, did you try including the correct plugin? are you still getting this error?

Comment: @NeilStockton: the solution provided by you worked. thanks a lot.

Comment: @Patrice : I am getting a new exception now. this one is resolved. Now i am getting this exception:- org.datanucleus.api.jdo.exceptions.ClassNotPersistenceCapableException: The class "com.gp.app.minote.backend.entities.EventEntity" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found.

Comment: @SandeepNautiyal IN that case, since the original question is answered, I would suggest opening a new question :) I will put Neil's suggestion as an answer in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was pointed out by [Neil Stockton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/380338/neil-stockton), your error message is unequivocal. You don't have the "datanucleus-appengine" jar as part of your CLASSPATH.